# React Native JSX error: elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag

Tags: react-native, jsx

I don't know why I'm getting the following error from my simulator:

```
Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag
```

**Code:**

```
render() {
    return (
    <View>
    <TextInput
        underlineColorAndroid={'transparent'}
        style={styles.searchInput}
        placeholder='Enter Part Name(s)'
    />

    <TextInput
        underlineColorAndroid={'transparent'}
        style={styles.searchInput}
        placeholder='Enter Basic Number(s)'
    />

    <Button
        onPress={this._onBackPressed}
        title='Go'
    </Button>

    </View>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The beginning of the View-tag (the start of the node) is missing. Also the button is missing the ">"

```
render() (
  <View> // this one were missing
    <TextInput
      underlineColorAndroid={'transparent'}
      style={styles.searchInput}
      placeholder='Enter Basic Number(s)'
    />

    <Button
      onPress={this._onBackPressed}
      title='Go'
    > // this one were missing
    </Button>

 </View>
)
```

Here you can read more at the JSX reference pages: https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html